# Thread from Callable stays in waiting state. How do I kill the Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, callable

There are a lot of similar questions, but no solutions have worked for me.

I have a Callable that needs to run for a certain amount of time. During execution of the Call method, it has to periodically do some checks in the while condition to check if it has to keep running. I also want to be able to stop the callable from outside (API call).

The code below is a simplified version but it has the same problem:

**When the callable returns, the thread stays in WAITING state. How do I kill this thread?**

```java
public class MyCallable implements Callable<Foo> {
    private AtomicBoolean stop = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    @Override
    public Foo call() {
        System.out.printf("New thread with ID=%d\n",
                Thread.currentThread().getId());
        Foo foo = new Foo();

        while (!stop.get()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000); // Sleep for some time before doing checks again
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }

        System.out.printf("State before returning foo: %s\n",
                Thread.currentThread().getState());
        return foo;
    }

    public void stop() {
        this.stop.set(true);
    }
}
```

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        MyCallable myCallable = new MyCallable();
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        Future<Foo> future = executorService.submit(myCallable);

        printThreads();

        System.out.println("Calling stop\n");
        myCallable.stop();

        while (!future.isDone()) {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        }

        System.out.println("After future is done: ");
        printThreads();
    }

    // Helper method
    private static void printThreads() {
        List<Thread> threads = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(t -> t.getName().contains("pool"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        threads.forEach(t -> System.out.printf("ID=%s STATE=%s\t\n", t.getId(), t.getState()));
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

This is the output of the program

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to manually kill threads managed by `ExecutorService`. You need to gracefully close the service and it will terminate its threads.

```
executorService.shutdown();
```

Usually, a thread-worker doesn't get terminated after a single task is done. It is moved to the `WAITING` state until a new task emerges. These things are managed by an `ExecutorService`. Shutting down it will lead to terminating the threads it is in charge of.

Comment: Thank you, this works!
Additional question: In my real application I make a new ExecutorService for every request (every new callable). Is this a good way to do it?

Comment: @SenneVerhaegen I feel like that would defeat the purpose of the ExecutorService.  It's there to manage which things are run, wouldn't creating one per Callable just be like running them unmanaged yourself?

Comment: @SenneVerhaegen usually one instance of `ExecutorService` is enough for most cases. Create it once, share it, and reuse it every time you need to submit a task.